# Failed to start marketing service in Sitecore 9.1.1 (Stopped Installation)

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.1 update 1 in my work machine and it always fails with the error "Failed to start marketing service". I have gone though many article and almost applied all the recommendation including giving IIS, IUSR and Local Service access to the certificates, check the trusted - untrusted certificates path with powershell command nothing works for me.

When I start the marketing service manually after installation fail it get started  I am not sure why the powershell (running as administrator) is not able to start the service.

I decided to skip this step of starting the service it works of me but at the end its getting another error "**Error requesting http://dj2.local/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be 
kept alive was closed by the server.**"

I have checked the event logs of this and surprised that something wrong with the SQLSERVER. I have SQL SERVER 2017 in my machine.

Logs from Eventviewer

```
Application: maengine.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Configuration.Extensions+<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<UseServiceDecorator>b__1(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.TransientCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IEnumerableCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(System.IServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ScopedCallSite, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.IServiceProvider)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.ServiceConfiguration.get_Engine()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.EngineService.OnStart(System.String[])
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[])
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.Program.RunAsService()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Engine.App.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

and another error is

```
Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: This configuration has not been initialized. Please call the initialize method before using it.
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.CheckInitialized()
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.get_CurrentModel()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0....
```

Anybody has any idea to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Just to let you know I have run this command as well **sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1**

Comment: could you check your license expiration ?

Comment: Make sure SQL Service are running ?

Comment: @Rameshkumar I have checked both License is Valid and SQL Service is running.

Comment: I have faced a similar error once, and it was related with the Service Name length. Can you check how many characters your service has? It should be less than 256.

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps Of course the service name is less than 256. In my case the service name is **"dj2.xconnect-MarketingAutomationService"** and it started manually after the installation failed.

Comment: @SrikantRahul thanks for checking, can you check if your Sitecore license is still valid?

Comment: Hi @ViniciusDeschamps, have checked the license is valid. And with the same license I have installed the Sitecore 9.1.1 in another machine. Something wrong with my machine.